# UIScrollView for iphone snaps to bounds where it shouldnt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have a paged scroll view in my app and it works almost perfectly... Usually one page looks like this:
[image]

There is no content below this, but when i move it as if it should scroll down (clicking and swiping upwards) it stops moving at this stage:

[image]

It's as if its decided that that is an acceptable page loaction or something. If i drag it part way up it snaps the rest of the way up, and if i drag it part way down it snaps all the way down.

Why is it considering this an acceptable place to stop? Is there an easy property to set im missing? Or is there a way to allow only horizontal scrolling?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `contentSize` property of the scroll view. That determines how far it will scroll, and you can manually set it to control exactly where it will scroll to.

Comment: Is there a way to get a good contentSize by calling view.contentSize or something of that nature? Im trying to avoid hard-coding my dimensions so I can adapt for iPad later

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want the scroll view to scroll exactly 2 page heights down, for example, you can do `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.x, view.frame.size.y * 2);`

Comment: I ended up fixing it with this line of code: self.levelScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(levelScroll.frame.size.width * NUM_CATEGORIES, levelScroll.frame.size.height);

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. Can you accept my answer since I described the property needed to control the scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Is the scroll view on 0,0 on the canvas? It looks like it is not actually centered on the screen.

Comment: I think that was just a sloppy screenshot job, but I'll check that. Thanks